# How to place buttons correctly in a layout - android

Tags: android

In my android app I have three buttons below. The problem I have is that these buttons are too close together and if I try to move one of them away then they all follow. Maybe because I state which button should go below who but I want to know if there's a way in my xml code to create a gap between these buttons?

[image]

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/brick_wall">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tic Tac Toe "
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_players1"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
            android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1 Player"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_players2"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2 Players"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="How to Play"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:paddingTop="50dp" to the all buttons??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve that by either adding margin to each button or you can add android:layout_marginTop="5dp" to the buttons below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:background="@drawable/brick_wall">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tic Tac Toe "
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_players1"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
    android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1 Player"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_players2"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_players1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
    android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2 Players"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_players2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
    android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="How to Play"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```